# Moving from internal raid to nas for video editing

Tags: network-attached-storage, windows-10, synology

I've got a two drive raid 0 in my main desktop for 9tb of usable storage. I actively use premiere pro and the adobe suite to produce videos that I am paid for and I do web development.

I backup to cold stored hard drives pretty frequently and have about 20 tb of data stored that way.

I'm thinking about moving to a nas for these reasons.

1) I could have a 4 drive Raid 5 accessible from the network for my main machine

2) I could access that from other machines in the office.

3) I could have access via wifi from my laptop

4) I could free up space in my main desktop and move to ssds for all of my desktop needs, 1 to hold assets, 1 to hold working files, 1 for exporting.

5) The NAS could act as a plex server to serve video to our tvs and media players

I'm thinking of going to the synology 916+ for the fact that I have synology servers in other locations for clients and they work well and are reliable. Plus they have some other features that would be handy, like video surveillance server and asterisk server.

Does anyone see any problems with this? Am I going to run in to trouble with editing this way that I'm not seeing? I have 10 4tb drives that I use for cold storage that I would continue to back up to in addition to this server but the server would hold files that I am using actively and then also allow me to back up my desktop and workstations actively without really thinking about it.

Thanks

Comment: Moving to Super User I guess. Sometimes I wonder why I use these sites lol.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not work directly from NAS, the only problem I am seeing is RAID 5. RAID 5 is deprecated. It has very slow write rates and for drives above 1 TB the resilvering takes so long that there is a good chance you are going to lose a second drive while the array is rebuilding. For this reason, go RAID 10 in your case, since you have cold storage anyway.

Reading speed will be limited by the network. If you build yourself a freeNAS for example, it would cost around the same, but you could put a 10 GBit card into it. A pair of 10 GBit cards has become very affordable.